# How to check if a Strings ends with any entry in a list of Strings in Java

Tags: java

I have a file name and a list of extensions. I want to check if the file name ends with any of the extensions in the list I have.

```
String fileName = "abc.txt";
String[] extensions = {".txt", ".doc", ".pdf"};
```

I can manually go over the list of extensions and check if the file ends with any of the extensions in my list.

```
public static boolean checkIfFileHasExtension(String s, String[] extn) {
    for (String entry : extn) {
        if (s.endsWith(entry)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    // your code goes here

    String fileName = "abc.txt";
    String[] extensions = {".txt", ".doc", ".pdf"};
    System.out.println(checkIfFileHasExtension(fileName, extensions));
}
```

Is there a better way of doing it using StringUtils or Streams or any other Java libraries? I am looking for a one-liner. Thanks!

Comment: For a one-off file name and a reasonable number of extensions, you're not likely to get a better solution in practice than the one you have. (Don't worry about trying to make it a one-liner: clear code is better than short code.) That said, I believe the best algorithm for this sort of problem in the general case would be to build a suffix tree and test against that.

Comment: Please explain the reason for the downvote?

Comment: @DanielPryden Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this.

```
public static boolean checkIfFileHasExtension(String s, String[] extn) {
    return Arrays.stream(extn).anyMatch(entry -> s.endsWith(entry));
}
```

Comment: Or `s::endsWith`

Answer (score 4):

If you use a `List` rather than a array, you could use the `contains(String)` method.
Besides, you could retrieve the extension by using the 
`lastIndexOf()` method of `String` combined with the `subString()` method.

```
List<String> extensions = Arrays.asList(".txt", ".doc", ".pdf");
boolean isContained = extensions.contains(fileName.subString(fileName.lastIndexOf(".")+1));
```

Comment: `contains()` on a `List` is O(N). If you want to go this route, a `Set` would be better performing and clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Apache Commons Lang [StringUtils.endsWithAny](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#endsWithAny-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) do exactly the same as your method. You can use it like:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    String fileName = "abc.txt";
    String[] extensions = {".txt", ".doc", ".pdf"};
    System.out.println(org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.endsWithAny(fileName, extensions));
}
```

But as was mentioned before it's performance linear to `extensions` so if you have a lot of them then try to extract the extension from the file name and make a lookup against a `HashSet`:

```
    String fileName = "abc.txt";
    String[] extensions = {"txt", "doc", "pdf"};
    HashSet<String> extensionsSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(extensions));
    String fileExt = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
    System.out.println(extensionsSet.contains(fileExt));
```

**Note:** the `HashSet` uses much more memory and thus it can work  slowly than linear search by array. If you use at as constant it's ok but if dynamically then measure your performance.

Also if you can use the prefixes as string you can try to use precompiled regexp: it may work even faster.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach is to tokenize using `.` as a delimiter

```
String fileName = "abc.txt";
List<String> extensions = Arrays.asList("txt", "doc", "pdf");

boolean checkExt(String fileName, List<String> extensions)
{
    String s = fileName.split(".");
    return extensions.contains(s[s.length-1]);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use [StringUtils.indexOfAny](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#indexOfAny-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-)

**Update**

From the javadoc -

```
public static int indexOfAny(CharSequence str,
                             CharSequence... searchStrs)
Find the first index of any of a set of potential substrings.

A null CharSequence will return -1. A null or zero length search array will return -1. A null search array entry will be ignored, but a search array containing "" will return 0 if str is not null. This method uses String.indexOf(String) if possible.

 StringUtils.indexOfAny(null, *)                     = -1
 StringUtils.indexOfAny(*, null)                     = -1
 StringUtils.indexOfAny(*, [])                       = -1
 StringUtils.indexOfAny("zzabyycdxx", ["ab","cd"])   = 2
 StringUtils.indexOfAny("zzabyycdxx", ["cd","ab"])   = 2
 StringUtils.indexOfAny("zzabyycdxx", ["mn","op"])   = -1
 StringUtils.indexOfAny("zzabyycdxx", ["zab","aby"]) = 1
 StringUtils.indexOfAny("zzabyycdxx", [""])          = 0
 StringUtils.indexOfAny("", [""])                    = 0
 StringUtils.indexOfAny("", ["a"])                   = -1
```

Comment: This answer is not helpful. Please add an example or something.